# The Sentence Would Be Grammatical

Tags: modal-verbs

Suppose a student asks a teacher whether a particular sentence is grammatical or not. The teacher has just a little bit of doubt about the grammatical correctness of the sentence. How would he comment on that sentence:

1. *The sentence **would be** grammatical.*
2. *The sentence **will be** grammatical*.

I think he couldn't reply with: *The sentence **is** grammatical*, because he is not **completely** sure. Likewise, I think, he cannot use: *The sentence **may/might/could be** grammatical*, because that shows too much doubt.

Comment: The ideal response might be: **Let me check on the construction to see whether the experts regard it as grammatical.**

Answer (score 2):

I would go with neither of those options and instead use an adverb with *is*:

> The sentence is *probably* grammatical.

You can use a thesaurus to find synonyms:

> The sentence is *likely* grammatical.

This is puts the statement as less certain than *is* alone but more certain than changing the verb.

Comment: You say: *This puts the statement as less certain than is alone but **more certain than changing the verb.***---Do you mean *The sentence **is** probably grammatical.* is more certain than *The sentence **would be** grammatical.* and this is the reason why you do not accept the latter?

Comment: "Likely" in this sentence would sound odd to most BrE speakers, although normal in American English.